# Generic Method That Inverts Booleans

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method with a generic parameter that filters values based on runtime string values.  It either lets the value through or returns the default();

```
public T Filter<T>(string target, string actual, T value)
    {
        bool isMatch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(target)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual)
            && target.ToUpper() == actual.ToUpper();


        return isMatch ? value : default(T);

    }
```

This works fine for most everything except booleans.  When a boolean false comes in and should be filtered, it comes back out as false -- the default() for boolean.

So what I want this to do when a `bool` is passed in is to return the inverse of the boolean.  How to get from `T` to `bool` and back into the return type `T`?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the method to return true in the case of `value == false`,`isMatch == false` and `T` is a `bool`?

Comment: why do you want the reverse of the truth? Then why don't you go for isnotmatch?

Comment: I can't see how this improves upon the conditional `?:` operator .. ?

Comment: The idea is to filter.  When the target and expected match, let a value through.  Otherwise, don't let the value through.  In the case of a bool, the only way to not let the value through is to invert it.

Comment: The implemented function has more to it -- I've peeled away the extra details that aren't relevant to my question.

Comment: @ZuluAlphaCharlie is the `target.ToUpper() == actual.ToUpper()` meant to compare reference? Or your intention is to compare the String content? If so you should use `target.ToUpper().equals(actual.ToUpper())` or `target.equalsIgnoreCase(actual)`

Comment: The `==` operator here is comparing string types.  I thought you had to use `.Equals()` when comparing objects of generic types?

Comment: Diego is thinking of Java, which unlike C# compares strings only by reference when using ==. However, for case-insensitive string equality, you should use the [Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) with StringComparison argument instead of comparing the uppercase strings in C#, as comparing the uppercase strings doesn't work for all cultures.

Comment: I recommend comparing strings using the `target.Equals(actual)` method so it does not look like a reference check with the `==` operator.

Comment: You can overload the method with boolean signature `bool Filter<T>(string target, string actual, bool value)`

Comment: The pitfall I see with having bool-specific overloads is, unless one knows that the overloaded method is required for bools, a developer can just `.Filter()` bools all day long without realizing thats `false` is not really being filtered untils tests fail.  On a similar note, I find it less-than-optimal to require that callers of the method know that situating the call to pass in a `true` to get the method to work as expected (yes, callers could just work around the vulnerability by first inverting any `false` into `true` when calling `.Filter()`).  But I think this defeats the utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I would use dtb's answer with default parameters. However, if you were for whatever reason unable to use it, here is my alternative.

I would refactor the matching code to a new method and overload the generic with a specific version for boolean values.

```
    public T Filter<T>(string target, string actual, T value)
    {
        return _match(target, actual) ? value : default(T);
    }

    public bool Filter(string target, string actual, bool value) 
    { 
        return _match(target, actual) ? value : !value;
    }

    private bool _match(string target, string actual)
    { 
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(target)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual)
            && string.Equals(target, actual, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```

When the 3rd parameter is boolean, the method call will resolve to the boolean version. When it isn't, it will resolve to the generic version.

Comment: Yes, I had considered this.  Was hesitant to go overloading the generic method if there was a way to do it elegantly in generics.  If not, so be it.

Comment: The only other *anything* I can think of that would "work" would involve a type check and cast inside the generic method (not 100% sure that would even work) - and that would be uglier. Changing the behavior of what you have `default(T)` doing would depend upon knowing the type at runtime.

Comment: It may very well be -- thus my question here.  Thought I'd check with the collective brilliance of stackoverflow denizens for some alternate perspective before giving up.

Comment: I don't really think I would consider overloading a generic method as giving up - if you need specific behavior on a type it is purpose built for the task - consider 7.5.3.6 of the C# Language Spec (v5.0)

Answer (score 2):

You could make this easier by using `bool?` as your generic type. When there's no match, `default(bool?)` will be `null`, which is quite distinguishable from `true` or `false`. This will also work for other primitive and values types, which will return `null` instead of a perfectly valid `0`.

Comment: This would force callers to handle null when they really just want to work with values types.  However, I could make a wrapper for `.Filter()` that handles this complexity cleanly and quietly.  Which is really waht I want: an encapsulated, one-stop-shop.

Comment: @ZuluAlphaCharlie: no, you really do want nullable, or some other out-of-band way to return a value that indicates that no value matched (as with the Maybe monad in Haskell). You're already doing that with reference types, as default(T) for any reference type is null.

Comment: Bottom line on this question - there's a gazillion ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered passing the default value to be returned to the method?

```
public T Filter<T>(string target, string actual, T value, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    bool isMatch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(target)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual)
        && string.Equals(target, actual, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

    return isMatch ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
Filter("foo", "bar", 42);          // returns 0
Filter("foo", "bar", false, true); // returns true
```

Comment: +1 This is good, but what if the caller of `Filter()` doesn't know the type it's passing to `value` (i.e. another generic type)? It wouldn't be possible to have `bool` working correctly in that scenario with this. We would be back to either overloading or dealing with bool as a special case inside `Filter()`

Comment: If the caller doesn't know the type, then the overload solution doesn't work as well. So the only option would be bool as a special case. But that's so ugly I wouldn't consider it. "generic" = same code works for all types.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, I was going to agree 100% until I tried it -  assume a type `Foo<T>` exists with my overload solution, `new Foo<object>().Filter("Bob", "Smith", false)` returns `true` as required and resolves to the overload with `bool`. See http://ideone.com/bPXLJi

Comment: In your first comment you said the caller would be generic and doesn't know the type. In your ideone code the caller clearly knows that the third argument is a bool and thus calls the right overload.

Comment: Now I understand - I was confusing "knowing the type" with the generic type specifier - when I boxed the bool value it didn't resolve to the overloaded method. Thank you for your patience and explanation. I updated the ideone code so you can see exactly what I mean.

Comment: While this works, it does require that the caller know to use the extra parameter to get bools to filter correctly.  I don't want clients to be forced to know this.